# What term describes insects that must eat protein to reproduce?

Tags: entomology, terminology

I know there is a specific term for insects that need to consume protein to produce viable eggs, as well as a term for those insects that don't need to consume protein to produce viable eggs.

Comment: I assume you are referring to species that needs to eat as adults before they can reproduce. Or are you only interested in species that specifically has to eat *protein* before they can reproduce (as adults or in general?)?

Comment: @fileunderwater I'm referring to a term that describes insect adults that must eat protein before they can reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term I was looking for was anautogeny, or an anautogenous insect. I had slightly confused the definition, with the actual definition being; '[a gravid female insect that requires a blood meal before oviposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anautogeny)'.

Comment: Well, if you are satisfied with your own answer to the question, you might want to accept it. :)